# Prolog gives is_absolute_file_name unhandled exception

Tags: prolog

i'm a total newbie in Prolog and learning it while taking a course in school. We have this big test coming up tomorrow and as i'm studying here i tried to do some tasks from previous versions of this test. One particular task was to take a string and put a "-" after every character "a". So for example word "example" would look like "exa-mple".

I wrote a code for it:

```
kriipsuga(S6ne,R) :-
  name(S6ne,X),
  write(X),
  goThrough(X,Y),
  name(R,Y).

goThrough([X|Xs],Y) :-
  X == 97,
  append(Y,[97],Z),
  append(Z,[45],O),
  goThrough(Xs,O).

goThrough([X|Xs],Y) :-
  X \= 97,
  append(Y,[X],O),
  goThrough(Xs,O).

goThrough([],Y) :- write(Y),Y.
```

This is the error:

```
?- goThrough([1,2,3,4],Y).
[1, 2, 3, 4]
ERROR: Unhandled exception: is_absolute_file_name/1: Type error: `text' expected, found `1'
```

Googling gave no results, maybe you guys could help me figure it out.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut `[File1, File2, ...]` is traditionally used in Prolog as a shorthand to the predicate that compiles and load a source files (usually, `consult/1`). The file argument is expanded into an absolute file path. In you code, the last clause is:

```
goThrough([],Y) :- write(Y),Y.
```

In your sample query, this clause ends up being used and a call `[1|_]` is made, hence the error you get. To make it clear, try to trace execution using the query:

```
?- trace, goThrough([1,2,3,4],Y).
```

Comment: I traced it and find the bug however i've kind of crashed and have no clue what to change. Could you give any pointers?

Comment: @Banana In `write(Y), Y`: what is the `Y` at the end supposed to do, anyway? If you can figure this out you will understand the answer.